# Ejabberd start issue. RPC Failed Node Down error

Tags: ejabberd

Im trying to configure my Ejabberd to run on Ubuntu. I have managed to successfully install the Ejabberd without any problems. When I try to start my server using

`ejabberdctl sid@domU-12-31-39-01-7C-F5.compute-1.internal start`

I get the following error

`RPC failed on the node 'ejabberd@domU-12-31-39-01-7C-F5': nodedown`

Im using Ejabberd 2.0.5 and I had a few installation issues earlier where I encountered a 'Post installation script error'. However after uninstalling and re-installing a couple of times I managed to get around it. I've used the installer to do my setup. I'd appreciate any help on how to solve this issue.

My log file shows the following:
This is what the log file says

> ```
> `=INFO REPORT==== 2010-02-03 07:52:44 ===
> ```
>
> I(<0.319.0>:mod_pubsub:155) : pubsub init "domu-12-31-39-01-7c-f5.compute-1.internal" [{access_createnode,
>                                                                                           pubsub_createnode},
>                                                                                          {plugins,
>                                                                                           ["default",
>                                                                                            "pep"]}]

```
=INFO REPORT==== 2010-02-03 07:52:44 ===
I(<0.319.0>:mod_pubsub:212) : ** tree plugin is nodetree_default

=INFO REPORT==== 2010-02-03 07:52:44 ===
I(<0.319.0>:mod_pubsub:216) : ** init default plugin

=INFO REPORT==== 2010-02-03 07:52:44 ===
I(<0.319.0>:mod_pubsub:216) : ** init pep plugin

 =INFO REPORT==== 2010-02-03 07:52:45 ===
I(<0.319.0>:mod_pubsub:224) : ** terminate default plugin

=INFO REPORT==== 2010-02-03 07:52:45 ===
I(<0.319.0>:mod_pubsub:224) : ** terminate pep plugin
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You will get that error if you dont 'sudo' . Use 'sudo ejabberdctl ...'

Comment: (doh) wasted hours installing ejabberd from sources on raspberry pi, installing by hand libyaml, chaing ejabberdctl hostname and ejabberd name...and it was so simple!

Comment: Getting same error even after using 'sudo'.

Comment: @Mahadev Check if you have your hostname properly set up. See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/201462/why-does-ejabberd-start-fail)

Comment: @Adil in my case i am not able to start ejabberd server with "sudo ejabberdct start" command, can you please help me out ?